# MySQL Workbench fails to make connection

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, linux-mint

completely new to MySQL, have no idea, just trying to learn, so any help would be deeply appreciated.

I installed the ubuntu version of MySQL Workbench although I have Linux Mint. Had to do this since there is no mint version. And besides most ubuntu apps work on mint, well, maybe.

But this may be causing the problems I am facing.

Even though I managed to install it on my mint box, when I started it for the first time I got a warning that it is unsupported (or something like that) and hence this can cause problems. I proceeded anyway.

Before going any further, I should point out that MySQL is working in a docker container. did not want to use docker this early, but its in the tutorial, so yeah.

I have made 2 connections but none of them work.

Here are the details on both these connections as they appear in 'Manage Server Connections'.

Connection Name: Connection1
Connection Method: Standard (TCP/IP)
Hostname: 127.0.0.1
Port: 3306
Username: v.je

Connection Name: Connection2
Connection Method: Standard (TCP/IP)
Hostname: 192.168.10.10
Port: 3306
Username: v.je

When I click on Connection1 under 'MySQL Connections' on the 'Welcome to MySQL Workbench' window, the SQL editor opens.

However, there is no 'SCHEMAS' category on the left-side pane. There are Management, Instance and Performance categories but no schemas. Because of this I cant proceed further on the tutorial I am using.

and on the top tab its written "Connection1- Warning - not supported".

WHy is this happening and what is the solution?

Connection2 simply does not work. When I click on it, an error message pops up saying "Your connection attempt failed for user v.je to the MySQL server at 192.168.10.10:330: Unable to connect to localhost"

There are so many possibilities, that I dont really know what to do. Any help to get it going would be appreciated, thanks a lot.

Comment: Thee are no Schemas in the first connection because you haven't created one .. Right click in the pane and "Create Schema"

Comment: Ah yes, it worked. Heres how

Comment: on the left pane you will find two tabs on top - 'administration' and 'schema'. click on schema tab, right click, select "Create Schema" and you are done. THANKS

Comment: One more question please. why is connection2 not working? When I click on it, an error message pops up saying "Your connection attempt failed for user v.je to the MySQL server at 192.168.10.10:330: Unable to connect to localhost"

Comment: I am assuming you're not connecting to the correct port: `192.168.10.10:330` should be `3306` ?

Comment: Connection Name: Connection2 Connection Method: Standard (TCP/IP) Hostname: 192.168.10.10 Port: 3306 Username: v.je

Comment: even with port 3306, connection2 is not working. Whats wrong?